# hamburger icon displaying incorrect size on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, icons

I am having some trouble using a hmaburger icon on my website.  it looks fine on larger viewports, but when you resize the window to be smaller (or view on a mobile device) the sizing of the bars become inconsistent and quite ugly.

I need to be using vmin sizing so it is completely responsive but can't figure out what the issue is.  Is there any way to fix this??

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-icon').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5vmin;
  top: 5vmin;
}
.menu-icon {
  width: 6.76vmin;
  height: 5vmin;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1vmin;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(25, 27, 29);
  border-radius: 1vmin;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
}
.menu-icon span:nth-child(2),
.menu-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 2vmin;
}
.menu-icon span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 4vmin;
}
.menu-icon.open span:nth-child(1),
.menu-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 2vmin;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
.menu-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.menu-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu-icon">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/).

Comment: Don't use `vmin`. Your hamburger should be approximately `50px` x `50px` but no less than 40. This ensures it is usable on all touch devices. You don't have to make it bigger/smaller depending on screen size. If you really insist on this, do it using breakpoints and use fixed sizes at which your lines look good on all devices.

Comment: As Andrei said, don't use `vmin` especially not for this part of your website.
There is just stuff you don't want to and should not resize.
Don't use FontAwesome though - Font icons tend to look weird on smaller screens.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input... I will try messing around with breakpoints and px sizing later.  Any reason in particular that vmin is causing this issue??  The reason I like vmin is because nearly everything else on the site I'm working on uses it (with no issues until this scenario) and I wanted consistency.  Also, couldn't really use FontAwesome anyway as I want the animation of the Hamburger Icon, which I don't believe FontAwesome icons accommodate??

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag you, @Sandro .  Do you also mind explaining why this question would be downvoted??  I normally avoid posting here because my questions seem to be received negatively by the community and if there is something I am missing I would love to know.

Comment: Well that is the way vmin works. vmin is essentially one percentage of the smaller viewport size (height or width). So if you make the screen smaller vmin gets smaller too.
As to why this question would be downvoted I have no idea. I voted it to zero again. Maybe you can ask the meta forum this question.

Comment: @Sandro thanks for that!!  I understand how vmin works essentially, what i dont get is why the three bars aren't displayed the same size as each other on smaller viewports?? for example the top one is fatter than the other two, but on a desktop they are all the same size as per the css.  I would really like to know why that is occurring but will switch to pixels for now.

Comment: When you are using vmin you get to a point when your measurements are in the subpixel range and then you can't guarantee that everything will be rendered nicely...